# Adventure Works Database Query producing empty output

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using following tables from adventure work to write a query:

[image]

The table FactInternetSales table has FK OrderDateKey, DueDateKey and ShipDateKey Assosiate with DateKey in DimDate table.

I have wrote following query to test:

```
SELECT dd.DateKey, dd.EnglishMonthName, fis.TotalProductCost
FROM DimDate AS dd INNER JOIN FactInternetSales AS fis 
ON dd.DateKey = fis.OrderDateKey AND dd.DateKey = fis.DueDateKey
AND dd.DateKey = fis.ShipDateKey
```

Above query produces empty output. I've checked the data in the FactInternetSales table and it has FK that associates with PK in the DimDate Table.What would be possible cause of this problem?

Please advise? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is extremely difficult to understand without having the Adventure Works Database (and I can't see your attached image), my guess is that FactInternetSales should only JOIN DimDate ON a single field.  Currently, the way you have the query written, you are joining DimDate.DateKey = FactInternetSales.OrderDateKey = FactInternetSales.DueDateKey = FactInternetSales.ShipDateKey

Unless those 3 fields in FactInternetSales are the same, this will never produce results.

Instead try something like:

```
SELECT dd.DateKey, dd.EnglishMonthName, fis.TotalProductCost
FROM DimDate AS dd INNER JOIN FactInternetSales AS fis 
ON dd.DateKey = fis.OrderDateKey
```

Good luck.